# Nestable jQuery plugin : Add an item dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use the jQuery plugin called Nestable available here :
https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

I try to add an item with a parent dynamically. But if I only add the code in the page, the expand/collapse button does not appear and I think there is a better solution to add item with setParent function ?

Does anyone has already added an item dynamically with this plugin ?

Comment: I am trying something same, did you get any solution? The Answers given in the thread are not relevant

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="appendnestable">Add li</button>
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
  <ol class="dd-list outer">
    <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="1">
      <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
      <div class="dd3-content" name="1">Item 1</div>
    </li>

    <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="2">
      <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
      <div class="dd3-content" name="2">Item 2</div>
    </li>

    <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="3">
      <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
      <div class="dd3-content" name="3">Item 3</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  var nestablecount = 4;
  $('#appendnestable').click(function(){
    $('ol.outer').append('<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="'+nestablecount+'"><div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content" name="'+nestablecount+'">Item '+nestablecount+'</div></li>');
    nestablecount++;
  });
});
```

**JSFiddles**

http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/35Kqu/

http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/YgU52/

**Food for Thought:**

The incremental counter is a good way to keep track of forms/modals assigned to each dynamically created list item, if needed.  Then, use the .on() or .delegate() jquery properties if further actions is required of said forms/modals.

Comment: Neither of your solutions solve the problem that he mentioned:  "the expand/collapse button does not appear"

Comment: How to save the nested data into a variable so that with PHP i can use this as menu?

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to add new node:

```
function addNode(){
    $("#nestable > ol").append("<li class='dd-item' data-id='13'><div class='dd-handle'>New Node</div></li>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we all have seen how to add items dynamically to nestable. 
I have written this code, where in you can create nestable items from JSON object.

```
//JSON Object

var json =  [{
  "id": 1,
  "content": "Payment Terms",
  "children": [{
    "id": 2,
    "content": "PT1"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "content": "PT2"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "content": "Delivery Terms",
  "children": [{
    "id": 5,
    "content": "dt1"
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "content": "dt2"
  }]
}];

Function to create nestable :

function makeNestableListUsingJSONArray(jsonArray, root) {

  if (typeof root === 'undefined') {
    root = $('body');
  }
  var $div = $('<div id="nestable"><ol class="dd-list"></ol></div>');
  root.append($div);
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
    var $li = $("<li class='dd-item' data-id='" + jsonArray[i].id + "'><div class='dd-handle'><span class='dd-content'>" + jsonArray[i].content + "</span></div></li>");
    root.find('ol.dd-list:first').append($li);    

    if (typeof jsonArray[i].children !== 'undefined') {
      makeNestableListUsingJSONArray(jsonArray[i].children, $li);
    }
  }
  $('#nestable').nestable({maxDepth:2});
}

call the function 
makeNestableListUsingJSONArray(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for supporting... I shall be adding more things in my next post like you can even edit the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is also new version of `Nestable` package that support loading items dynamically from JSON and adding new item to the list on-the-fly. Read more here: https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2

```
$('.dd').nestable('add', {"id":1,"children":[{"id":4}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late to answer, but for anyone facing the same issue with buttons not showing, this is the solution I've come so far.

```
$('#nestable').nestable();
$('[data-action="collapse"],[data-action="expand"]').remove();

let collapseBtnTemplate = '<button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button><button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>';
let expandBtnTemplate = '<button data-action="collapse" type="button" style="display: none;">Collapse</button><button data-action="expand" type="button">Expand</button>';

$('#nestable > ol:first-child > li.dd-item').each(function(){
    $(this).prepend( $(this).hasClass('dd-collapsed')? expandBtnTemplate : collapseBtnTemplate );
})
```