# Nestable jquery plugin add list dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Nestable works well when we try to add a single list item as described here([Nestable jQuery plugin : Add an item dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120896/nestable-jquery-plugin-add-an-item-dynamically))

But it doesnt work well if we try to add a whole new list(ol element).

It doesnt show the expand option when we try to add new ol element dynamically.

Any help is appreciated.

jsfiddle to describe the issue : http://jsfiddle.net/0zrsnt44/

```
// activate Nestable for list 1
$('#nestable').nestable()

$(function () {
    var nestablecount = 4;
    $('#appendnestable').click(function () {
        $('ol.outer').append('<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="' + nestablecount + '"><div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content" name="' + nestablecount + '">Item ' + nestablecount + '</div></li>');
        nestablecount++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are looking for. Your code appears to do what you are asking it to do. Can you provide more info? Your code isn't adding an `ol`, it is adding and 'li' to an existing `ol`.

Answer (score 1):

To create a Nestable sub-list you have to follow this pattern:

```
<ol class="dd-list outer">
    ...
    <li class="dd-item addnewlist" data-id="4">
        <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>

        <!-- Dynamically added >>>>>> -->
        <ol class="dd-list outer">
            <li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
                <div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <!--  <<<<<<  -->

    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

I.e. the sub-list should be placed after `div.dd-handle` and must itself contain `li.dd-item` and `div.dd-handle` elements inside it.

But even if you get this right, there's a bigger problem besides that: Nestable won't know that there are new elements in the underlying DOM so it won't properly initialize them, create expand/collapse buttons, etc. Moreover it has no means for the user to explicitly reinitialize/redraw it.

You can either fork the plugin and add the needed functionality or try to hack and extend it from your code.

Here's my attempt at it which creates a `reinit` method that can be called after modifications to the DOM of the list to update it:

```
(function($) {
    var $plugin = $('<div>').nestable().data('nestable');

    var extensionMethods = {
        reinit: function() {
            // alias
            var list = this;

            // remove expand/collapse controls
            $.each(this.el.find(this.options.itemNodeName), function(k, el) {
                // if has <ol> child - remove previously prepended buttons
                if ($(el).children(list.options.listNodeName).length) {
                    $(el).children('button').remove();
                }
            });

            // remove delegated event handlers
            list.el.off('click', 'button');

            var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document;
            if (hasTouch) {
                list.el.off('touchstart');
                list.w.off('touchmove');
                list.w.off('touchend');
                list.w.off('touchcancel');
            }

            list.el.off('mousedown');
            list.w.off('mousemove');
            list.w.off('mouseup');

            // call init again
            list.init();
        } // reinit
    };

    $.extend(true, $plugin.__proto__, extensionMethods);
})(jQuery);
```

This method can be called like so:

```
$('#nestable').nestable('reinit');
```

Full example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/uh5eL5sc/)

Comment: Works well, But if we have a other lists collapsed, then it expand button changes to collapse without expanding the list. updated the jsfiddle to explain the issue http://jsfiddle.net/uh5eL5sc/23/

Comment: Updated JSFiddle, reinit resets items to expanded state.

Comment: Works well, but not much satisfied with this because it just expands all the available nodes when we add a new node. It has to expand only the node where we are adding the new item to and all other nodes has to stay as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is readily similar to that of Dekkard.  You'll see I made it ca. 11 months ago on CodePen when the future of nestable.js seemed to be brighter than it currently is in terms of development support.  I thought it was worth including so you can see what else can be done with that plugin.

Check out my CodePen: http://codepen.io/mijopabe/pen/xlcjq.

You can create and use a counter to keep track of which specific list item you created and are manipulating:

```
$(function(){
  var nestablecount = 4;
  $('#appendnestable').click(function(){
  $('ol.outer').append('<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="'+nestablecount+'">
<div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content" name="'
+nestablecount+'">Item '+nestablecount+'</div><div id="c-'+nestablecount+'" 
class="content"><form role="form-'+nestablecount+'"><div class="form-group"><label 
for="name">Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" 
placeholder="Phyllis Wheatley"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="name">Add a 
Description</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Quite the poet">
</textarea><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="">Now you know it ;)
</label><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">Yes</button></div>
</div></form></div></li>');

  updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
  nestablecount++;
  });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                Hello All,

                My approach is very simple and is readily readable.

                Add 2 jquery files in your project :- 1) nestable.js 2) nestable.css

                **HTML**

                <label>Enter Your Data</label>
                <input type='text' id='tncInput'>
                <button id="appendnestable">Add Data to li</button>
                <div class="dd" id="nestable">
                  <ol class="dd-list outer"></ol>
                </div>

            **jQuery** 

            $('#nestable').nestable();

            $(function() {
              var nestablecount = 1;
              $('#appendnestable').click(function() {
                var tnc = $('#tncInput').val();
                var html = '<li class="dd-item" id="' + nestablecount + '"  data-id="' + nestablecount + '"><div class="dd-handle"> ' + tnc + '</div></li>'
                $('ol.outer').append(html);
                $('#tncInput').val('')
                nestablecount++;
              });
            });

        This is how you will be able to enter your data dynamically to LI.
    Moreover, you can even change some nestable configuration settings as follows :

    $('#nestable').nestable({maxDepth:2, group:1});

    maxDepth :- number of levels an item can be nested (default 5)
    group:-  group ID to allow dragging between lists (default 0)

Thanks!!
```